# ZipArchive in PHP7 cannot find content of zip

Tags: php, zip, extract, php-ziparchive

I have a PHP script to unzip a zip file from a form,
but whatever content i put in the zip, the opened zip cannot find the items.
When I `var_dump()` my zip I get this:

```
object(ZipArchive)#800 (5) {
    ["status"]=> int(0) ["statusSys"]=> int(0) 
    ["numFiles"]=> int(0) 
    ["filename"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php83KJHe" 
    ["comment"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

here is the script:

```
$zip     = new  \ZipArchive();
$zipname     = $_FILES[ 'lezip' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
$zip->open( $zipname, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE );
var_dump( $zip );
$zipsuccess = $zip->extractTo( $destination );
var_dump( ' success: ' . $zipsuccess );
```

the success dump says it is ok

```
string(11) " success: 1"
```

And i did set up the $destination folder, it exists and have write access.

Why can't ZipArchive find any items to the zips i upload ?

Comment: Debug:
$open_status = $zip->open(...);
var_dump($open_status);
Share the output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php#ziparchive.constants.overwrite) on `ZipArchive::OVERWRITE`:

> Always start a new archive, this mode will overwrite the file if it already exists.

You can't use this flag if you wish to read an existing archive.

Comment: great, it works by setting the flag CREATE only, thanks